# How make a table with php using the echo command with looping data?

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table, echo

I want to make a nice looking table for my SQL data.

I load in my data like this now:

```
$sql = "SELECT mednr, mednaam, medvoornaam , medemail, ploeg, medgeslacht FROM Medewerker, Ploeg WHERE medploeg = ploegnummer";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["ploeg"] == "Tapper") {
        echo 
    "<td class='link2'>" . $row["mednaam"] . "</td>".
    "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medvoornaam"] . "</td>".
    "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medemail"] . "</td>".
    "<td class='link2'>" . $row["ploeg"] . "</td>".
    "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medgeslacht"] . "</td>".

        '<form id="delete" method="post" action="">'.
        '<input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $id; ?>"/>'.
        '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>'."</form>".
    "</br>"."</hr>";
            ;
    }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

But I want to make a nice looking table. The problem is that the echo keeps looping the data so I cant make `<table>` and `<td>` tags because it will create a table and td for each piece of data.

I know from jQuery were I could use `$append` to put the data inside a certain tag.

Is there any way I could do this with PHP?

(I'm very new to PHP and programming in general so please excuse me for this simple question).

Comment: Why can't you just style the <table>'s ID?

Comment: Because when I place the table in the echo it will create a table for each row

Comment: I think you wanted to add code there? Use shift+enter to go to a newline haha

Comment: Hahah yea sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke this is how I got it to work, by ending the php code when I wanted to creat a table.

Thank you for your help!

```
    $sql = "SELECT mednr, mednaam, medvoornaam , medemail, ploeg, medgeslacht FROM Medewerker, Ploeg WHERE medploeg = ploegnummer";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
?> <table id='table2'> <tbody><?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Table header -->
        echo "<thead>".
            "<tr>".
                '<th scope="col" id="...">This is the table header</th>'.

            "</tr>".
        "</thead>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["ploeg"] == "Tapper") {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='link2'>" . $row["mednaam"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medvoornaam"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medemail"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='link2'>" . $row["ploeg"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medgeslacht"] . "</td>";
            echo "</br>"."</hr>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    }
    ?></tbody></table><?php
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: `<tbody>` should be outside the loop

Comment: Now, the `<thead>` should be outside the `<tbody>`. echo the `<tbody>` just before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some table tags in you code (like `<table>`, `<tr>`). Check the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp. Also you can close php code anywhere with `?>`, add html code and continue php code with `<?php` anywhere you want if you want more transparent code.

Comment: Oke but If I place the table in the echo it will make a table for each row of the echo because it loops.

Comment: You can do something like this: `?><td class='link2'><?php echo $row["mednaam"]; ?></td><?php`. But it's up to your preferences. The main thing here is that you're missing some table tags in your code.

Comment: Who says you need to echo the <table> tag inside the loop?

Comment: Where would I want to stop the php code? If I place it outside the loop it makes a table for the first data and drop the rest in the body.

Comment: You should place `<table>` before loop and `</table>` after loop. You need to wrap all `<tr><td>some text</td><td>2nd column text/td></tr>` with table tag. I suggest you to try to create the table in pure html at first and then add php code to generate data from db.

Answer (score 1):

```
// .....

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";

    // you can also echo table headers here

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["ploeg"] == "Tapper") {
            echo 
            "<tr>" .
            "<td class='link2'>" . $row["mednaam"] . "</td>".
            "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medvoornaam"] . "</td>".
            "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medemail"] . "</td>".
            "<td class='link2'>" . $row["ploeg"] . "</td>".
            "<td class='link2'>" . $row["medgeslacht"] . "</td>".
            "</tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
// .....
?>
```

Comment: When I do that he makes a table for the first loop of data and he just echos the rest.

Answer (score 0):

As Micer said, add TABLE and TR tags. 
Also you don't need a single echo. Its very hard to work with one echo which is very long. You can also write as many echos for each TD separately. While writing it, do all the design you want within it, like making it bold, adding maybe colors, or alignment, etc.

And just while you are trying to fix it, add a limit to your SQL so it only shows 10 rows in the loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT mednr, mednaam, medvoornaam , medemail, ploeg, medgeslacht FROM Medewerker, Ploeg WHERE medploeg = ploegnummer LIMIT 0,10";
```

Comment: I wrote more echo's for all the td and other tags. But it doesn't solve my problem. I still cant create a table for all my rows and not a table for each row.